# FOLLOWLOCATION и open_basedir

Tags: php, curl

Возникает подобная ошибка при использовании CURL.

`Warning: curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set in /var/www/*******/data/www/*******/script/Threads.php`

Понятно что проблема с некой директивой `open_basedir`,но просто выключить нельзя по определенным причинам.Изменить можно.
Возможно прописать какое-нибудь исключение php.ini?

Или какие есть альтернативные варианты решения `CURL FOLLOWLOCATION`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю делать перенаправления не средствами curl, а кодом на php. Вот пример метода получения данных по $url:

```
private function _Request($url, $timeout = 10, $max_redirects = 10)
{
    $allow_url_fopen = strtolower(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));
    $ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0';

    // 1
    if (extension_loaded('curl'))
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close($ch);

        if ($content !== false)
        {
            // переадресация
            if (($http_code == '301' || $http_code == '302') && $max_redirects > 0)
            {
                if (preg_match('%Location:\s(http[^\n\r]+)%i', $content, $matches))
                    return $this->_Request($matches['1'], $timeout, $max_redirects - 1);
            }

            // отдаем ответ
            else if ($http_code == '200')
            {
                $content_start = strpos($content, "\r\n\r\n");
                if ($content_start !== false)
                    return substr($content, $content_start + 4);
            }

            // прерываем выполнение
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    // 2
    else if (function_exists('file_get_contents') && in_array($allow_url_fopen, array('on', 'true', '1')))
    {
        $stream_context = stream_context_create(
            array(
                'http' => array(
                    'method'        => 'GET',
                    'user_agent'    => $ua,
                    'max_redirects' => $max_redirects + 1,  // PHP >=5.1.0 only
                    'timeout'       => $timeout // PHP >=5.2.1 only
                )
            )
        );

        return file_get_contents($url, false, $stream_context);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Параметр open_basedir создан для обеспечения безопасности, ограничивая доступ к открытию файлов указанием директории, выше которой этого сделать нельзя.

Чтобы отключить его, найдите в php.ini open_basedir и замените cтроку на open_basedir = none

Если отключить его не представляется возможным, то нужно проверять код ответа и переходить по заголовку Location самостоятельно.