# Как получить урл конечного сайта при редиректе

Tags: php

Имеется такой код, который следует по ссылке `http://domen.com/redirect/`, в которой имеется перенаправление на другой сайт, к примеру yandex.ru:

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 18);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://domen.com/redirect/");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Задача такая стоит - нужно получить урл конечного сайта, потому что сайт на который происходит редирект постоянно разный. 
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: Пример есть тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/553109/186083

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот такой параметр:

```
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```