# cURL получить итоговый url после редиректа, редиректов

Tags: php, curl

Пытаюсь получить итоговый url адрес по реферальной ссылке.
Оказалось, что прежде чем перейти на основной сайт, ссылка делает 2 редиректа
Выполняю код

```
// инициализация сеанса 
$ch = curl_init(); 

// установка URL и других необходимых параметров 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$url = 'http://gpclick.ru/affiliate/8258228'; 
$headers = get_headers($url, 1); 
print_r($headers['Location']);
```

Результат

[image: результат]

Как получить чистый итоговый url - http://www.joysignals.ru ?
twitter.com при этом вообще отказывается выдавать результат по ссылкам вида  https://t.co/oIPiZmAfXI - из-за чего это может быть?

Спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/669739/186083

Comment: Так получай последний элемент массива.

Comment: Получил с помощью `echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);` итоговый url адрес, теперь думаю как преобразовать его в имя домена http://site.ru из http://site.ru/vasy/pupkin/news.html и т.д.

Comment: теперь домен выбери регуляркой

Comment: помогите составить запрос для поисковиков... нахожу только регулярку которая вытаскивает имя домена а мне нужно еще и протокол

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/39811/186083